# How can we extract data from grafana dashboard?

Tags: python-3.x, graphite, grafana-api

Need to extract specific data from grafana dashboard. Grafana is connected to graphite in the backend. Seems there is no API to make calls to grafana directly.

Any help?

Ex: I need to extract AVG CPU value from graph of so and so server.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found in grafana 7.1 was to:

1. Open the dashboard and then inspect the panel
2. Open the query tab and click on `refresh`
3. Use the url and parameters on your own query to the api

*note*: First you need to create an API key in the UI with the proper role and add the `bearer` to the request headers